# best approximation of $f$ in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ as a linear combination of $\sin(kx)$ (with $k∈\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function. Assume that $f$ is quadratic integrable in the interval $[0,2\pi]$. Consider $f$ as a vector in the Hilbert space $L^2([0,2\pi])$. Give, based on the Fourier coefficients of $f$, the best approximation of $f$ in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ as a linear combination of $\sin(kx)$ (with $k∈\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$

Answer:
I think {$\frac{sin(kx)}{\pi}|k=1..10$} is an orthonormal set. So the best approximation is the orthogonal projection on $K= span${$\frac{sin(kx)}{\pi}|k=1..10$} What is the next step? Taking the imaginary part of de fourier coefficients, or is that not the meaning?

Comment: Yes the sins are the imaginary parts of the Fourier coefficients. However it is important that the frequencies of the complex exponentials and the sines are the same or there would not be orthogonality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approximation minimizes the following over all possible $\{ a_k \}_{k=1}^{10}$:
$$
               d(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{10})=\left\|f - \sum_{k=1}^{10}a_k \sin(kx)\right\|^2.
$$
The best approximation is the same as the orthogonal projection, meaning that $\{ a_k\}_{k=1}^{10}$ are chosen so that
$$
    \left(f-\sum_{k=1}^{10}a_k \sin(kx),\sin(nx)\right)=0,\;\;\; n=1,2,\cdots,10.
$$
You end up with a system of 10 equations in 10 unknowns, and the system has a unique solution because the set of functions $\{ \sin(kx) \}_{k=1}^{10}$ is linearly independent.
This generalizes what you learned in Calculus connecting closest distance and orthogonal projection. Orthogonal projection gives the Fourier coefficents because $(\sin(kx),\sin(nx))=0$ for $n \ne k$; that is,
$$
      (f,\sin(nx))-a_n(\sin(nx),\sin(nx))=0.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
  a_n & = \frac{(f,\sin(nx))}{(\sin(nx),\sin(nx))} \\
      & =\frac{\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx}{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^2(nx)dx} \\
      & =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(x)\sin(nx)dx.       
\end{align}

Comment: @bob : Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @bob : You're welcome.